# How to get Redux state before render for child component prop?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-state

I have a component that renders another component, and it depends on the `currentUser` state in Redux. However, upon initial load, the value is undefined. How do I enforce that the value is defined before proceeding?

The component with the state:

```
import { Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import DataScroll from "./navigation/DataScroll"
import Post from '../components/partsbin/Post'
import SidePanelCard from '../components/SidePanelCard'
import { getPosts } from "../gql/queries"
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
const theme = makeStyles({})

export default function HappeningNow(props: any) {
  const styles = theme()
  const { currentUser } = useSelector(({ uiState }: any) => uiState)

  const handleGetPosts = async (offset: number, limit: number) => {
    try {
      const data = await getPosts(offset, limit, null, currentUser?.uid || null)
      console.log('params being passed: ', offset, limit, null, currentUser?.uid)
      console.log('data returned', data)
      return data
    } catch(e) {
      return e
    }
  }

  return (
    <Grid container flexDirection="column">
      <Grid item>
        <Typography
          variant="h6"
          sx={{ fontWeight: "bold", textAlign: "center" }}
        >
          Happening Now
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <DataScroll ItemComponent={SidePanelCard} limit={12} getApiItems={(offset: number, limit: number) => handleGetPosts(offset, limit)} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

As you can see, I'm setting `currentUser` via `useSelector`, but the query `handleGetPosts` is firing before `currentUser` is being defined. How do we guarantee that the value is set? Is it good practice to wrap a global state with local state? Is there a way to use `useSelector` in a `useEffect`? I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: When you get the value `currentUser ` the component will re-render. So you may add a simple condition to check if `currentUser ` is available or not. Like `{currentUser 
 && <DataScroll ItemComponent={SidePanelCard} limit={12} getApiItems={(offset: number, limit: number) => handleGetPosts(offset, limit)} />}` . Now `handleGetPosts` should get triggered only if `currentUser ` is set.

Comment: Wow - I'm an idiot. I was calling `uiState` instead of `userState` - :/ I also forgot to add that conditional. Thank you for setting me straight! I need to take a nap haha

Comment: I will post it as an answer to earn some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the value `currentUser`  the component will re-render. So you may add a simple condition to check if `currentUser`  is available or not. Like,

`{currentUser   && <DataScroll ItemComponent={SidePanelCard} limit={12} getApiItems={(offset: number, limit: number) => handleGetPosts(offset, limit)} />}` .

Now `handleGetPosts` should get triggered only if `currentUser`  is set.

Comment: This, in addition to my idiotic name mistake was the problem. Thanks again!